# setAttribute does not set value

Tags: javascript, aframe, ar.js

Executing the following code:

```
 var marker = document.createElement('a-marker');
 marker.setAttribute('preset', 'hiro');
 marker.setAttribute('scale', '0.75 0.75 0.75');
 sceneEl.appendChild(marker);
```

and inspecting the resulting document gets:

```
<a-marker preset="hiro" scale="" arjs-anchor="" material="" arjs-hit-testing=""></a-marker>
```

Preset is set correctly, but scale doesn't have the value in there. If I change `scale` to `randomName`, it gets set properly. What am I doing wrong? Note that I am using ar.js, which created the a-marker element type, which is an extension of a-entity of the aframe framework.

Edit: Minimal reproducible code added.  the code snippet console logs the same, i.e. scale not being set.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/1.0.4/aframe.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githack.com/AR-js-org/AR.js/master/aframe/build/aframe-ar-nft.js"></script>
    <script>
        window.onload = () => {
          var sceneEl = document.querySelector('a-scene'); 
        var marker = document.createElement('a-marker');
        marker.setAttribute('preset', 'hiro');
        marker.setAttribute('scale', '0.75 0.75 0.75');
        console.log(marker);
        sceneEl.appendChild(marker);
        };
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false" embedded
        arjs="sourceType: webcam; debugUIEnabled: false;">
    </a-scene>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code looks fine , are you still sure for this situation...

Comment: instead of inspecting, I did a console.log like Scott Marcus showed below, the console displayed the same output as above, again, working correctly if I change scale to randomName.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I cannot comment (not enough point).
Would be curious to hear if you got this resolved.  I have the very same issue (posted an example on gitter: https://gitter.im/AR-js/help-and-support?source=orgpage)

```
var model = document.createElement('a-box');
model.setAttribute('gps-entity-place', latlngInfo);
model.setAttribute('material', 'color: red');
model.setAttribute('scale', '0.21 0.21 0.21');
scene.appendChild(model);
```

Like you, if I put a random attribute name, the value is then set. It seems to break when using the ar.js attribute names in my case.  So really interested in how you solved it!

Comment: Unfortunately no.  I'm working on an another aspect of my project while letting it sit in the back of my mind for now.